# Determining if a ListViewItem is fully or only partially visible in the WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem, adorner, adornerlayer

I have a WPF ListView.  This ListView will contain n-items.

As a user drags something into the listview, I am displaying a horizontal bar on the AdornerLayer of the ListView to show the index where the item will be inserted.

I also am auto-scrolling the listView.  Because ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ListViewItems are partially visible.

The problem I am having is that the indicator bar that I am drawing is appearing outside of the bounds of the ListView (in my case above) when the ListViewItem I am over is at the top and only partially visible.

The trigger to draw the bar is to take whatever ListViewItem I am currently hovering over, grab it's top bounds value and draw the line.  When the ListViewItem is not fully visible yet, the bar is draw above the ListView itself and obviously looks weird.

Summary: Trying to determine if a given ListViewItem is only Partially visible in a ListView.

In this case, code is not really all that relevant but I can post some if you like.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  I thought I saw something that with 2012 you can get it not to crop.  Only a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use a combination of `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` or `ScrollViewer.ViewPortHeight` and the listviewitem's location with respect to the listview itself

```
itemPosition = ListViewItem.TransformToAncestor(ListView).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

To tell if it is fully visible you should just need to do the following

```
itemPosition.Y + itemHeight - viewPortHeight
```

Then if that value is between the `itemHeight` or `-viewPortHeight`, then it is visible

OR, what is probably a little cleaner:

```
(-itemPosition.Y < itemHeight && itemPosition.Y < viewPortHeight)
```

Comment: This was it.  I needed one more transform.  With the above transform, I can simply check to see if the .Y value of that point is < 0.

Comment: This doesn't work for regular `ListView`s where `CanContentScroll` is usually `false`.  I that case the `viewPortHeight` is the number of items that can be displayed in the viewport and not the actual height in pixels: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportheight(v=vs.110).aspx